# Q: Is it possible to create & add a bitmap straight into Timage without saving to file first

Tags: delphi, bitmap, bitmapimage, timage

I can make it work via creating the bitmap and saving it to a file. (The bitmap is a barcode). Afterwards loading it into the TImage via ppimage1.Picture.LoadFromFile(filepath);

With this way of doing it, you have to create and delete a temp directory for your image. I'd rather not do this if possible...

Answer (score 2):

You can assign directly to the `Picture` graphic:

```
ppimage1.Picture.Assign(myBitmap);
```